# How to see a list of running processes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How can I see a list of running processes (like seen in the windows task manager) in windows Powershell?

Comment: @user2328314 - You are getting downvoted because it is expected that you do try to look for a solution yourself before posting a question.  You couldn't have looked very hard because the very first google result when typing in your question's exact title tells you the answer.

Comment: It is ironic that this is now the first google result.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The command [Get-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855.aspx) is what you're looking for

Comment: And you can get something along the likes of top with a little tuning: http://superuser.com/questions/176624/linux-top-command-for-windows-powershell